# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Native Android app unable to connect when using HTTPS

Tags: android, https, native, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a simple Android Hybrid and Native Application developed using Worklight 6.0. Over http both the apps work fine with connecting to the server and invoking a procedure. But as soon as I move to https, hybrid app works fine, but I can see that the native connect request itself is not received at the server end.

Do I need to enable anything else to get https working on the android native app?

Comment: What/where did you change thus far? Please edit the question with details.

Comment: I've deployed worklight server on WAS V8.5. 9060 is the admin port. http port is 9080 and 9443 is the https port. I've followed the notes in the worklight developer works getting started site and have written an Android native app to do a connect and invoke a procedure. Connect on http port 9080 works but if I try connect on 9443 (https) port it does not connect. WAS logs do not show a request being received.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To use HTTPS, you need to configure your SSL certificate on your WAS server. The SSL certificate should not be self-signed, but signed by a trust CA like VeriSign.
To configure SSL certificate on WebSphere application server, here's the [doc](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/csec_sslconfigs.html&resultof=%2522%2553%2553%254c%2522%2520%2522%2573%2573%256c%2522%2520) for you.